# Truncated content with Apache on Vagrant VM

Tags: macos, virtualbox, apache-http-server, vagrant

I'm using Vagrant to run a CentOS VM in order to try and achieve local development parity with our live servers. I've symlinked `/var/www/html` with the `/vagrant` shared directory and am forwarding port 80 for viewing at `http://localhost:4567`. I'm developing using SublimeText 2 on OS X Mountain Lion.

Once I figured that iptables was tripping me up, all was well and good. Until I noticed something strange.

I have a sample HTML page consisting of several paragraphs of lorem copy. I can view this fine in a browser on OS X. But when I make an edit, for example removing a paragraph, and refresh the content is truncated with the paragraph I deleted still visible.

When I `cat` the files on the server I can see the changes I made but these aren't even reflected when I `curl localhost`.

I strongly suspect that it's a problem with my Apache settings — with which I didn't really tinker — as the issue doesn't arise when I stop Apache and run `sudo python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80` in the directory to view pages instead.

What gives?

Comment: This seemingly only affects HTML files. The exact same file served via PHP doesn't exhibit this issue. Which just confuses me more...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We also use OSX, Vagrant and a symlinked setup,we experienced similar issues.
The following worked for us, add this to you apache conf.

```
EnableSendfile off
```

The solution was found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298933/shared-folder-in-virtualbox-for-apache.
Hope that helps.